# How to find ways to vote when some candidates receive no votes using PIE

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

There is 15 voters, and 4 candidates. The candidates are part of these 15 voters, and they can vote on themselves. Each voter must cast a vote. Now, how many possible ways can the votes be cast if at least one candidate receives no votes?

My idea for a solution would be to add up cases where at least one candidate is not a voting option. Using $\binom{m+n-1}{n}$ where m is candidates and n is voters, I would add $\binom{3+15-1}{15}$ and $\binom{2+15-1}{15}$ and $\binom{1+15-1}{15}$. I think that is a valid way of approaching the problem with combinatorics.

However there is a hint below that reads "Let $A_i$ be the set of all outcomes where person $i$ receives no votes. Now use principle of inclusion exclusion.

How would I write that set $A_i$? And then how would I use PIE on said set? This way of approaching the problem seems complicated and I am unsure of where to start. Even a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: My first thought would have been:  use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to find the unrestricted number of patterns, then use Stars and Bars again to find the number of patterns in which every candidate gets at least one vote, and then subtract to get your answer.

Comment: Using inclusion-exclusion is relevant if your technique involves counting cases where $A$ gets no votes and cases where $B$ gets no votes (etc.), since you will double-count cases where both $A$ and $B$ get no votes.

Comment: ${18\choose 15}$ would spread $15$ votes over $4$ candidates.  ${17\choose 15}$ spreads 15 votes over 3 candidates.  This is not optimal there are 4 cases where one candidate gets no votes and cases were 2 candidates get no votes.  ${14\choose 11}$ gives us the result if every candidate receives at least one vote.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at Doug, but I am going to try using what the other two comments suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|$. By inclusion exclusion, this is
$$
\sum_i |A_i|-\sum_{i<j}|A_i\cap A_j|+\sum_{i<j<k}|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|.
$$
Now, 
$$
\begin{align}
|A_i|&=\binom{15+3-1}{15}\\
|A_i\cap A_j|&=\binom{15+2-1}{15}\\
|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|&=\binom{15+1-1}{15}\\
|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|&=\binom{15+0-1}{15}=0\\
\end{align}
$$
Finally, counting the number of times each term is repeated, you get
$$
|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4|=\binom41\binom{15+3-1}{15}-\binom42\binom{15+2-1}{15}+\binom43\binom{15+1-1}{15}
$$

Comment: Just to be clear, each term on the right side of the equation is multiplied because you are considering each combination of candidates getting zero votes, right?

Comment: That's right. The first term $\binom{15+3-1}{15}$ is multiplied by $\binom41$ since you are adding up, for each candidate, the number of combinations where they do not get a vote. Then the second terms is multiplied by $\binom42$ since you are subtracting, for each _pair_ of candidates, the number of combinations where neither person in the pair gets a vote.